# Having a N:N Relationship that links 2 different entity types in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: many-to-many, dynamics-crm-2011, entity-relationship

I need to be able to link for example Customers to either multiple Users or multiple Teams.
Now I managed to do this for a lookup field using a JavaScript but I have no idea how to do it for a Many-to-Many relationship.

Basically I need to find a way to re-enable the 'Look for' field when searching for example for multiple users and also allow the option to search for multiple teams as well.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to do this with two seperate many-to-many relationships.

1. Contact and System User
2. Contact and Team

This is the best way to do, even if it doesnt give the most streamlined of UIs. But thats the way Mscrm was designed to work.

Comment: +1, but I don't if "that's the way Mscrm was designed to work" is the best way to put it. `Customer`s can refer to either `Contact`s or `Account`s, and `ActivityPointer`s can refer to any activity type, etc. I think it's better said that "that's a limitation that Mscrm doesn't impose on *itself* but instead forces *you* to work with."

Comment: Yes, it would be nice if Crm was a little more consistent.

Comment: ok will have to add another relationship I guess... that was my escape option to tell you the truth... lets just hope the client doesnt have anything to say about it :P thx :)